# Evaluating $\int_0^1\int_{0}^y (y-x)(xy)^{a-\frac{3}{2}} [(1-x)(1-y)]^{b-\frac{3}{2}}\,dx\,dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, beta-function

Consider the integral $$\int_0^1\int_{0}^y (y-x)(xy)^{a-\frac{3}{2}} [(1-x)(1-y)]^{b-\frac{3}{2}}\,dx\,dy$$

The answer is $$\frac{4\Gamma(2a-1)\Gamma(2b-1)}{\Gamma(2a+2b-1)}$$ where $\Gamma(a)$ is Gamma function.
The result can be verified numerically by choosing some $a$ and $b$.
I wonder how to prove this fact.

This result is related to an extension of Beta distribution on 2d plane.

Comment: What are the conditions on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers.